# How do I increase age so that it updates the deafult value in the class? Java

Tags: java

**SOLVED IT**

The age of the dog can be increased by one year only and shouldnt be able to decrease it. My code still has error saying the age is not increasing. The way it should work in the small dog register program is that in the menu there will be an option "increase dog age" which when chosen it aks for dog name that was previously stored (doesnt matter right now), it just says "you have updated the dogs age" without user input, it just adds 1 to the current age. I hope this explains better, the assignment only needs me to do the dog class for now and pass the tests, one of them are those below the code.

```
//instead of the:
public void setAge(int newAge) {
    if (newAge > this.age) {
        this.age = newAge;
    } else {

        System.out.println("Age cannot decrease. Keeping the current age.");
    }
}
//i have tried this and it solved the test errors:
public void increaseAgeByOne() {
       if (age < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            age++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Age cannot be increased further due to overflow.");
        }
    }
```

```
public class Dog {
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private int age;
    private int weight;
    private double tailLength;
    private static final double TAIL_LENGTH_FOR_DACHSHUND = 3.7;
    

    public Dog(String name, String breed, int age, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.tailLength = tailLength;
        normalLetters();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int newAge) {
    if (newAge > this.age) {
        this.age = newAge;
    } else {
        
        System.out.println("Age cannot decrease. Keeping the current age.");
    }
}
    
   ...

    
}
```

I have found other similar solutions to the one I already have but none are working. Also the second I remove the one Ii already have it shows more errors from the test that the age is not increasing.

The test that checks the age increase:

```
@Test
    @Order(130)
    @DisplayName("Age can be updated")
    public void ableToIncreaseAge() {
        Dog dog;

        dog = new Dog(DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_BREED, DEFAULT_AGE, DEFAULT_WEIGHT);
        callAssumedMethodForIncreasingAgeOfDog(dog, 1);
        assertEquals(DEFAULT_AGE + 1, dog.getAge());

        dog = new Dog(DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_BREED, DEFAULT_AGE, DEFAULT_WEIGHT);
        callAssumedMethodForIncreasingAgeOfDog(dog, 3);
        assertEquals(DEFAULT_AGE + 3, dog.getAge());
    }

    @Test
    @Order(140)
    @DisplayName("Age cannot decrease")
    public void unableToDecreaseAge() {
        Dog dog;

        dog = new Dog(DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_BREED, DEFAULT_AGE, DEFAULT_WEIGHT);
        callAssumedMethodForIncreasingAgeOfDog(dog, -1);
        assertEquals(DEFAULT_AGE, dog.getAge());
    }

    @Test
    @Order(150)
    @DisplayName("Age cannot decrease through overflow")
    public void unableToDecreaseAgeThroughOverflow() {
        Dog dog;

        dog = new Dog(DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_BREED, Integer.MAX_VALUE, DEFAULT_WEIGHT);
        callAssumedMethodForIncreasingAgeOfDog(dog, 1);
        assertEquals(Integer.MAX_VALUE, dog.getAge());
    }
```

Comment: better include a [mre] in this type of question. We cannot see how `setAge()` is being called, so hard to know what is going on - if I do `var dog = new Dog("Alfa", "mix", 1, 10);
        dog.setAge(2);` with posted code, it works as expected - no error, age is set to 2

Comment: I don't see a default value to be updated.  Can you please explain more and provide an example and the errors you encounter.

Comment: missing in posted code: "increased by one year only"; but that does not match the description "error saying the age is not increasing"

Comment: The question title doesn't match the description.  The description refers to tests failing but these are not included so we don't know what is being tested.  Your description includes a restriction that the age may only be incremented by 1 but that is not enforced in the method - that is probably your issue but there isn't enough here to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this. No need for error messages etc.  Change the name of the method as you see fit. Using `setAge()` implies a less restricted action on the value.

```
public void updateAge() { // or incrementAge()
   this.age++;
}
```

**Updated**

One thing to consider is to insure your constructor does not permit negative ages (an age of zero would indicate a puppy).  After all negative ages don't make much sense.  Then your set method could be something like:

```
public void setAge(int newAge) {
    if (this.age+1 == newAge) {
         this.age = newAge;
    } else {
         System.out.println("Age may only increase AND by 1.  Age remains unchanged.");
    }
}
```

But I still think the `setAge()` method is not appropriate to limit the age in that way when a more properly named method would be more descriptive.  And since you can control that method to work exactly as you desire, no verification or error message is required.

But keep in mind that someone can always "set" the dog's age to any value greater than one by writing their own method.  Here is an example:

```
public void updateDogsAge(Dog dog, int years) {
    while(years-- > 0) {
       dog.setAge(dog.getAge()+1);
    }
}
```